# Highlighting DataGridView Row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell-formatting

I want to highlight DataGridView rows depending on value. If value is validated then green if not then red.
I get the green and red when cell has not been formatted before. However when I go back to the green row and change its value which is not validated one cell does not change to red. It stays green.
See the pictures:
1)Without any entry
[image]
2)Entered Validated value
[image]
3)Went back and entered wrong value
[image]
As you can see only first cell is red, but I want whole row to be red.

I am formatting cells in CellValidating event. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub dgvItems_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgvItems.CellValidating
    If e.ColumnIndex = ValueColumnIndex Then
        If Not ValidateValue(e.FormattedValue) Then
            Me.dgvItems.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
            Me.dgvItems.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightPink
            Me.dgvItems.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            Me.dgvItems.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight
            Me.dgvItems.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText
            Me.dgvItems.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Me.dgvItems.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Properties of the DataGridView, look for Focus > RowValidating, as illustrated in the image below.

[image]

Something like this should do it for you.

```
Sub DataGridView1_RowValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs)

   Dim drv As DataRowView
   Dim c As Color
     If drv.Item("Gender").ToString = "M" Then
       c = Color.LightBlue
     Else
       c = Color.Pink
     End If
     e.CellStyle.BackColor = c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to reformat an entire row then use the `RowValidating` event handler.

If you want to restyle a single cell with the validation then use `CellValidating`

The line:

```
Me.dgvItems.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SystemColors.Highlight
```

Has a global effect on the default cell style of the whole grid so set these changes on `Load`,then let your event handlers do your conditional formatting.